# Determine numbers $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$, $x_{4}$ such that Matrix equation holds

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-calculus

I need to determine a set of numbers  $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$, $x_{4}$, such that the following holds true:

$(x_1\cdot y_1) + (x_2\cdot y_2) + (x_3\cdot y_3) + (x_4\cdot y_4) = (e_1) + (e_1) + (e_3) -(x_4\cdot e_4)$

Where $y_{1}-y_{4}$ is column vectors of a Matrix $Y$:

\begin{bmatrix}2&-3&8&1\\-4&-3&-2&-2\\2&4&1&3\\2&4&16&1\end{bmatrix}

and $e_{1}-e_{4}$ are column vectors of a Matrix $E$

\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{5}&-\frac{4}{5}&\frac{2}{5}&\frac{2}{5}\\-\frac{4}{5}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{2}{5}&\frac{2}{5}\\\frac{2}{5}&\frac{2}{5}&-\frac{1}{5}&\frac{4}{5}\\\frac{2}{5}&\frac{2}{5}&\frac{4}{5}&-\frac{1}{5}\end{bmatrix}

I am not looking for someone to solve this equation for me, but rather a helping hand as to how I would engage solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left-hand side is $YX$ where $X$ is the column vector $[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]^T$.  The only problem is that you have an unknown $x_4$ on the right.  Move the $x_4e_4$ term over to the other side, and you can adjust the $Y$ matrix so that you have a typical system of $4$ linear equations in $4$ unknowns.

Comment: If I get it right, you would simply substitute the final row in $Y$ such that $y_4$ becomes $x_4a_4$-$x_4q_4$ = $a_4-q_4$? As I see it the right hand site would be displayed as $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0\end{bmatrix}^T$?

Comment: The right hand side is given as $x_4-x_4$= 0, for the last row. I don't know if that is correct, but I assume this, as the right hand site must have values to allow defining specific values for the numbers of $x_1-x_4$?

Comment: The last term becomes $x_4(y_4+e_4)$  So change$Y$ by adding $e_4$ to $y_4$.  I don't understand why you are talking about rows.  Don't you mean columns?

Comment: Yes of cause columns, I have just been determining row spaces, so guess I just got had my mind elsewhere. Yeah also meant $y_4+e_4$. How about the right side? Here I'm thinking the values of $x_1-x_4$, which holds the values of these numbers when I have reduced the system to row echelon..

Comment: Once you move the last term to the left, the right-hand side is just a constant vector; it's the sum of three given vectors.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot for the clarification! :-)